# VS 2017 hangs while loading windows workflow .xamlx file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have old Windows Workflow Service solution with bunch of Workflow Services ( .xamlx) files. I recently installed VS 2017 and also installed WF extension for VS 2017.
When i open `.xamlx` file for the first time it opens fine, then if i close the tab and try to open the `.xamlx` file then VS keep showing 'opening the file` popup window and it hangs.

I have to kill the VS instance from task manager and start all over again. and then same thing happens again. VS keeps hanging..

Why its hanging? where can i find logs about the actual error?

Comment: Does your xamlx have custom designer code in it? Wondering if there is some logic that runs when the designer is loaded/loading that has a compatibility issue with VS2017's hosted designer.

Comment: One place to look is in the Windows Event Viewer administration panel. It may actually log unhandled exceptions from .NET applications.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with WF in VS 2017 on machines with touch screens. I had to disable the touch screen and pen in Device Manager to get the designer to work properly.
Supposedly, they are adding tests to catch this in the future, but I'm not holding my breath for updates to WF. Not sure if this WF or Windows issue, but here are some related articles with varying workarounds:

[Visual Studio Community issue on WF designer specifically](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/47158/visual-studio-crashes-when-opening-workflow-xaml-f.html)

[Visual Studio Community on larger Windows issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55303/visual-studio-may-terminate-unexpectedly-when-runn.html)

The second article has more localized fixes that don't require you to disable touch.